# Как не учитывать энтеры, пробелы и/или знаки припинания при подсчете символов в Memo?

Tags: delphi

```
 var x:integer;

 x:=Length(TMemo1.Text);
 TMemo7.Text := IntToStr(x);
```

---

**Update 1**

```
Str := TMemo1.Text;
Count := 0;
for i := 1 to Length(Str) do begin
  if Str[i] in [#13, #10, ' ', ',', ';'] then
    Continue;
  Inc(Count);
end;
```

Возникают следующие эрроры:

```
'(' expected but ':=' found
Undeclared identifier: 'Count'
'(' expected but ')' found
'(' expected but '[' found
Incompatible types: 'Set' and 'Char'
```

Comment: Очевидно, предварительно пройтись по строке и выкинуть лишнее.

Comment: > Undeclared identifier: 'Count'

Объявите переменную `Count`.

Вот работающий пример: http://ideone.com/1Jbbs6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Str := TMemo1.Text;
Count := 0;
for i := 1 to Length(Str) do begin
  if Str[i] in [#13, #10, ' ', ',', ';'] then
    Continue;
  Inc(Count);
end;
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос, в нем эрроры. Как их устранить?